# How to populate the ListBox in GWT on Page load

Tags: gwt, listbox, uibinder, listboxitem

I am trying to add items in my Listboxes on page load in GWT. I have tried doing:

```
    UserProviderAsync userProvider = GWT.create(userProvider.class);
    userProvider.getTx(new AsyncCallback<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
        {
            Window.alert("Error caught: " + caught);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String[] result)
        {
            for (String tx : result) {
                Listbox.addItem(tx);
            }

        }
    });
```

But this is throwing an error on these 2 lines:
    RootPanel.get("gwtContainer").add(Request);
    private RequestUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(RequestUiBinder.class);
saying that there is some uibinder module missing and it gives an error for on EntryPoint.

Can some one please help me how can I add items to the ListBox in GWT.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. You need to post the part where you create the Request widget, and also the error message.

Comment: I have just called this from my onmodule class using  RootPanel.get("gwtContainer").add(new Request());. And this is how I am trying to put some static data which is on the proxy server:  public class getUserListImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements UserNmList
{
 @Override
 public String[] getUserName() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  String[] user= {"user100","user200","user300"};
  return user;

 }

Comment: The problem is not here. The problem is with a UiBinder, which is not related to your data or your calls. It's related to the way you create your widgets.